# Redux store returns different states for different components (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm pretty new to redux and have been trying to debug this issue. Basically i have two components which are unrelated (not a parent-child nor child-parent nor siblings) and I would like to utilize Redux for global state management to pass data from one component to the other.

The code works in a sense that Component A is able send the data to the store. Logging store.getState() on component A, I am able to see the new updated state. However, logging store.getState() on component B, I am not able to see this same updated state. (item will be empty)

Using ReduxDevTools extension, I am able to see that the state is updated in component A after `onPress` method is invoked but not for B.

*Component A state updated*: 
[image]

*Component B state unchanged*: 
[image]

**Component A**

```
class a extends Component {

 // implementation code

   onPress = r => {
      this.props.sendProblem(r)
      // console.log(store.getState())
   }

 // implementation code

 }

 A.propTypes = {
   sendProblem: PropTypes.func.isRequired
 };

 export default connect(null, {sendProblem})(A)
```

**Component B**

```
// implementation code 

componentDidMount() {
// console.log(store.getState())
}

// implementation code

B.propTypes = {
  item: PropTypes.object
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   item: state.items.item
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(B);
```

** problemReducer **

```
import { ABC } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    item: {}
}

export default function(state= initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) { 
        case ABC: 
            return {
              ...state,
              item: action.payload
            } 
        default:
            return state; 
    }
}
```

** problemActions **

```
import {
   ABC
 } from "./types";

export const sendProblem = r => dispatch => {
     dispatch({
      type: ABC,
      payload: r
    })
};
```

** Root Reducer **

```
// implementation code 

export default combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  errors: errorReducer,
  items: problemReducer
});

// root reducer used in store.js to create store
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you

Comment: `running store.getState() on component ` you should not do that in components and I don't see any of that code. You dispatch sendProblem in compnent A but where that comes from nobody knows because it doesn't exist as an action. How does `export const ABC = r => dispatch => {` not cause an error because you already defined it here: `import { ABC } from './types'`? I don't think the code you posted has anything to do with the code that produces the error for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response HMR. Apologies, code was `export const sendProblem = r => dispatch => {`, had a typo there @HMR. Just a clarification that i'm not getting any errors from the compilation of code, the issue is rather that the state is updated and logged correctly only in component A and not B.

Comment: `onPress = r => {` what is r supposed to be? You can replace `export const sendProblem = r => dispatch => {` with `export const sendProblem = r => ({
      type: ABC,
      payload: r
    })` it will be dispatched because you use connect

Comment: In the reducer you set `state.item` and in mapStateToProps you get `state.items.item`. At no point are you setting `state.items` anywhere so that should error in cannot get property item of undefined when your mapStateToProps runs.

Comment: Hey @HMR , i'm not too sure if that's the issue as I have brought in `state.items` in the combined reducer (edited shown above), thanks